# How to deactivate button in Xamarin With ICommand

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icommand

I got an application which has 2 buttons. First is counting up, second says "set 0" in Xamarin forms. I want the upcountButton do get Gray/Disabled when the value of 512 get hit.
here my Code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> Nummer { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>();
    private int _currentNumber;
    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand CountUpCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand DelCommand { get; private set; }

    Number Zahl = new Number();

    public CounterViewModel()
    {
        CountUpCommand = new Command(CountUp);
        DelCommand = new Command(SetZero);
    }

    public void SetZero()
    {
        Current = 0;
        Nummer.Add(new NumberViewModel { Num = Current});
        Checker(Current);

    }

    public void CountUp()
    {

            Current++;
            Nummer.Add(new NumberViewModel { Num = Current });
        Checker(current);


    }
    public void Checker(int check)
    {
        if (check > 512)
        {
            //button.grayout
        }
        else { }
    }
```

So how can i bind this to the enable-status of my button?

Oh, I forgot my xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Button Text="+1" Command="{Binding CountUpCommand}" x:Name="plusOne" />
        <Button Text="DEL" Command="{Binding DelCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
<Label Text="--------------" />
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Nummer}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell 
                Text="{Binding Num}"
                x:Name="ElNr"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each command has a [`CanExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.command.canexecute) method.

When you return `false` from that method, the related button will appear as disabled.

Just make sure you call the [`ChangeCanExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.command.changecanexecute) to notify the UI that the command status changed.

For example:

```
public CounterViewModel()
{
    CountUpCommand = new Command(CountUp, CanCountUp);
}

public int Current
{
    get
    {
        return _currentNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentNumber = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        CountUpCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
    }
}


public void CountUp()
{
    Current++; //will result in calling CanCountUp and updating button status
    Nummer.Add(new NumberViewModel { Num = Current });
}

public bool CanCountUp()
{
    return Current <= 512;  
}
```

P.S. You should use camelcase for public member names, for instance `Current` instead of `current`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181884/discussion-on-answer-by-shimmy-how-to-deactivate-button-in-xamarin-with-icommand).